# Add a new line of text at the top of a file in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a bash script that takes my file:

**READ_ME.MD**

```
two
three
four
```

and makes it

**READ_ME.MD**

```
one
two
three
four
```

There are a bunch of similar StackOverflow questions, but I tried their answers and haven't been successful.

These are the bash scripts that I have tried and failed with:

---

**test.sh**

```
sed '1s/^/one/' READ_ME.md > READ_ME.md
```

Result: Clears the contents of my file

---

**test.sh**

```
sed '1,1s/^/insert this /' READ_ME.md > READ_ME.md
```

Result: Clears the contents of my file

---

**test.sh**

```
sed -i '1s/^/one\n/' READ_ME.md
```

Result: sed: 1: "READ_ME.md": invalid command code R

---

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could write to `READ_ME.md.tmp`, and then `mv READ_ME.md.tmp READ_ME.md`. Or use `cat READ_ME.md | sed ... > READ_ME.md`. The problem is you're truncating the file before it's read.

Comment: Use >> to append to the file.  > will overwrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `BSD sed` command:

```
sed -i '' '1i\
one
' file
```

`-i` will save changes inline to `file`.

---

If you want to add a line at the top if same line is not already there then use `BSD sed` command:

```
line='one'

sed -i '' '1{/'"$line"'/!i\
'"$line"'
}' file
```

Comment: If I didn't want to save a backup would I just omit the `.bak` extension?

Comment: @anubhave that doesn't modify the file. It just prints the result.

Comment: No need to worry about if it's there. It doesn't work if I use `sed -i` using terminal on macOS. `sed: 1: "READ_ME.md": invalid command code R`

Comment: You should have told OSX earlier :). On OSX use: `sed -i ''` to ignore ` backup files.

Comment: You're right. Sorry about that! Is there docs for OSX bash?

Comment: This is not BASH issue. BSD `sed` behaves differently and documentation of that is `man sed`. btw did you try edited answer?

Comment: I did. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your last example works for me with GNU sed. Based on the error message you added, I'd guess you're working on a Mac system? According to [this blog post](http://markhneedham.com/blog/2011/01/14/sed-sed-1-invalid-command-code-r-on-mac-os-x/), a suffix argument may be required on Mac versions of `sed`:

```
sed -i ' ' '1s/^one\n/' READ_ME.md
```

Comment: `-i""` is **exactly** the same as `-i`  -- there's no possible way `sed` can distinguish them, since they generate the same array of C strings after being parsed, and the actual OS-level interface whereby programs are invoked is the `execve` syscall, which accepts only such an array (and doesn't receive or otherwise have access to the original command line in full). Thus, it *absolutely must* be `-i ''`, with a space, to pass an empty string.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't considered that. Edited. Thanks, Charles!

Comment: `-i ' '` ->  with a space

Answer (score 1):

If this is bash or zsh, you can use process substitution like so.

```
% cat x
one
two 
three

% cat <(echo "zero") x
zero
one
two 
three
```

Redirect this into a temp file and copy it back to the original

Answer (score 0):

there is always `ed`

```
printf '%s\n' H 1i "one" . w | ed -s READ_ME.MD
```